# JXTable: use a TableCellEditor and TableCellRenderer for a specific cell instead of the whole column

Tags: java, swing, tablecellrenderer, tablecelleditor, jxtable

I have a `JXTable` compound of 6 columns and two of them are `JCheckBox`. I would like to have the following behavior:

- If the first checkbox is checked, the second checkbox is enabled and can be checked or not.
- If the first checkbox is unchecked, the second must be disabled and unchecked.

I edited an image with Photoshop to show the desired result:
[image]

For the `CheckOne` and `CheckTwo` columns i use a custom `TableCellEditor` and `TableCellRenderer` :

```java
public class CheckBoxCellEditor  extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor { 

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox();

    public CheckBoxCellEditor() {       
        checkBox.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, 
            Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column)  {       

        checkBox.setSelected(value==null ? false : (boolean)value);             
        return checkBox; 
    } 


    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() { 
        return checkBox.isSelected(); 
    }
}
```

```java
public class CheckBoxCellRenderer extends JCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CheckBoxCellRenderer() {
        setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        setSelected(value==null ? false : (boolean)value);              
        return this;
    }

}
```

And this is how i set them:

```java
//CheckOne
table.getColumn(4).setCellEditor(new CheckBoxCellEditor());
table.getColumn(4).setCellRenderer(new CheckBoxCellRenderer()); 
//CheckTwo
table.getColumn(5).setCellEditor(new CheckBoxCellEditor());
table.getColumn(5).setCellRenderer(new CheckBoxCellRenderer());
```

I tried to add a `PropertyChangeListener` to the `JXTable` and implement the behavior from there, but i couldn´t get it done.

Then i realised that my custom editor and renderer were changing all the column components at the same time instead of only the desired component.
So, i tried to make the changes in the `TableCellEditor` and `TableCellRenderer`, and in the `PropertyChangeListener` but, again, i couldn´t figure it out.

Comment: J(X)Table has implemented JCheckBox as Renderer/Editor, rest of question is about methods in model, e.g. setValueAt it shoud be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off please note your problem is not related to JXTable but renderers / editors / model.

As @mKorbel points out JCheckBox is the default Renderer/Editor for booleans and generally speaking you won't need to re-invent the wheel: just override [getColumnClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#getColumnClass-int-) properly to return Boolean on both 5th and 6th columns.

However, because of this requirement:

> *If the first checkbox is unchecked, the second must be **disabled** and unchecked.*

This is not the default renderer's behavior so you actually need your own renderer. **But** only renderer, you don't need an editor: as @mKorbel points out you need a little work with the table model.

#### Renderer

```
class CheckBoxCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

    private final JCheckBox renderer;

    public CheckBoxCellRenderer() {
        renderer = new JCheckBox();
        renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        Color bg = isSelected 
                ? table.getSelectionBackground() : table.getBackground();

        renderer.setBackground(bg);
        renderer.setEnabled(table.isCellEditable(row, column));
        renderer.setSelected(value != null && (Boolean)value);
        return renderer;
    }
}
```

#### Model

You need to work on both [isCellEditable()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#isCellEditable%28int,%20int%29) and [setValueAt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#setValueAt%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) methods to properly update your second booleans column based on values on first one. For instance consider this snippet:

```
// A default model with 5 rows and 6 columns
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(5, 6) {
    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch(columnIndex) {
            case 4:
            case 5: return Boolean.class; // Both 5th and 6th columns are booleans
        }
        return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        /*
         * In order to know if 6th column is editable, you have to check
         * 5th column's value.
         */
        if(column == 5) {
            Object value = getValueAt(row, 4);
            return value != null && (Boolean)value;
        }
        return super.isCellEditable(row, column);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
        /*
         * If 5th column value is updated to FALSE, you need to 
         * set 6th column's value to FALSE as well
         */
        if(column == 4) {
            super.setValueAt(Boolean.FALSE, row, 5);
        } 
        super.setValueAt(aValue, row, column);
    }
};
```

---

### Test it

Here is a complete test case. Hope it helps.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

/**
 * @author dic19
 */
public class Demo {

    private void createAndShowGui() {

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(5, 6) {
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                switch(columnIndex) {
                    case 4:
                    case 5: return Boolean.class;
                }
                return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                if(column == 5) {
                    Object value = getValueAt(row, 4);
                    return value != null && (Boolean)value;
                }
                return super.isCellEditable(row, column);
            }

            @Override
            public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
                if(column == 4) {
                    super.setValueAt(false, row, 5);
                } 
                super.setValueAt(aValue, row, column);
            }
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.getDefaultRenderer(null);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setCellRenderer(new CheckBoxCellRenderer());

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class CheckBoxCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

        private final JCheckBox renderer;

        public CheckBoxCellRenderer() {
            renderer = new JCheckBox();
            renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

            Color bg = isSelected 
                    ? table.getSelectionBackground() : table.getBackground();

            renderer.setBackground(bg);
            renderer.setEnabled(table.isCellEditable(row, column));
            renderer.setSelected(value != null && (Boolean)value);
            return renderer;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Demo().createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```