# JTable set disabled checkbox look for uneditable cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, boolean, jcheckbox

I have `JTable` with a boolean values column. Depending on the state stored in model I make some or all of them uneditable (model's `isCellEditable()` returns false). However this does not make the `JTable` boolean renderer to render the checkboxes as disabled for uneditable cell.

Is there a way how to achive this other than writing custom boolean renderer?

If I need to write my own renderer what class should I extend other than `JCheckbox`? I just simply need to disable the checkbox before rendering and do not want to implement all the rendering code and handle selected look and stuff.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: agree with an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for JTable/XxxTableModel in local variable

Answer (score 4):

> *However this does not make the JTable boolean renderer to render the checkboxes as disabled for uneditable cell.*

This is correct, because it's the default renderer's behavior: `JCheckBox` is uneditable but not *disabled*.

> *Is there a way how to achive this other than writing custom boolean renderer?*

No, as far as I know.

> *If I need to write my own renderer what class should I extend other than JCheckbox?*

It's not mandatory to extend any class to implement [TableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) interface. You can perfectly have a `JCheckBox` as renderer's class member. Actually, composition is preferred over inheritance.

> *I just simply need to disable the checkbox before rendering and do not want to implement all the rendering code and handle selected look and stuff.*

It's not that difficult and you can control what is happening. Consider the example below:

```
class CheckBoxCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

    private final JCheckBox renderer;

    public CheckBoxCellRenderer() {
        renderer = new JCheckBox();
        renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Color bg = isSelected ? table.getSelectionBackground() : table.getBackground();
        renderer.setBackground(bg);
        renderer.setEnabled(table.isCellEditable(row, column));
        renderer.setSelected(value != null && (Boolean)value);
        return renderer;
    }
}
```

See this Q&A for a related problem: [JXTable: use a TableCellEditor and TableCellRenderer for a specific cell instead of the whole column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209796/jxtable-use-a-tablecelleditor-and-tablecellrenderer-for-a-specific-cell-instead)

Answer (score 0):

Without a working example it is hard to say exactly what is wrong, but it sounds like you may have forgotten to fire a table modification event to notify the JTable it needs to repaint itself.  You need something like this in your model when you make your change:

```
fireTableChanged(new TableModelEvent(sourceModel, firstRow, lastRow, tableCol));
```

There are different table change events you can fire and different parameters you can pass to the TableModelEvent constructor.  You can find more information in the Javadocs here:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api and the Java Tutorials here:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#fire.  You will need to have a read of these to work out which ones are right for your particular circumstances.

I doubt a custom boolean renderer would be required.